# How to redirect to home page if url is invalid

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

here is my code

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<User/>} />
    <Route path='/:userId/places' exact element={<UserPlaces/>} />
    <Route path='/places/new' element={<NewPage/>}/>
    <Route path='/places/:placeId' element={<UpdatePlace/>}></Route>
</Routes>
```

I want to redirect to the homepage if anything other than these URLs is entered, but using the redirect method in the latest version is not supported.

Comment: Redirecting to the home page is very poor user experience.  You should show an error page (or redirect to a 404 Not Found error page) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#navigate) component effectively replaced the older `Redirect` component. Render a "wildcard" route that renders a redirect to your home page route.

Example:

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
```

is equivalent to RRDv5's `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />`

Code:

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<User />} />
  <Route path='/:userId/places' element={<UserPlaces />} />
  <Route path='/places/new' element={<NewPage />} />
  <Route path='/places/:placeId' element={<UpdatePlace />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add all matching `Route` at the end of your `Routes`:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  ...
  <Route path='*' element={<Home/>}></Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with `React Router`. If no page is found then you can use `*` in Path ‍and the `element` you can use your preferred component Like `<Homepage />` or `<NotfoundPage />`

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<User/>} />
    <Route path='/:userId/places' exact element={<UserPlaces/>} />
    <Route path='/places/new' element={<NewPage/>}/>
    <Route path='/places/:placeId' element={<UpdatePlace/>}></Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<Homepage/>} />
</Routes>
```